# Possible to publish from Rails through Socket that runs on Node?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, websocket

Let's say I run server with node.js and I attach Socket.io to it.
Now I can emit from it and let's say my front-end app can talk to it.

Can I use Rails to emit to the same front-end app through using that Socket server I ran with node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to emit directly from rails to the same socket.

What you can do is setup an inter process communication (IPC) between rails & node.js, and when a message is received from rails, emit that message to the front end.

Here's an example using unix sockets, which require that your rails & node.js app run on the same machine.

```
const net = require('net');
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000); // Socket.io server

const socketName = '/tmp/ipc.sock';
const unix = net.createServer(connection => {

    connection.on('data', data => {

        // data may be a JSON with a room name & message
        // If data is big enough, you may need to buffer data
        // and emit on `end`

        io.emit('some-event', data.toString()); // Emit data

        // connection.write('something'); if you want to send data back to rails

        connection.end();

    });

});

unix.listen(socketName, () => {
    console.log(`Socket started at ${socketName}`);
});
```

I don't know any ruby, but now you will need to write to `/tmp/ipc.sock`

It should look something like this (Again, I don't know ruby)

```
require 'socket'
socket = UNIXSocket.new("/tmp/ipc.sock")
socket.puts('some data')
# or maybe socket.write('some data')
```

Unix sockets is one of many ways to handle IPC, you can use `Redis`, `RabbitMQ` or whatever you may like or feel comfortable with.